# Tracking a user change in active directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm writing an application that needs to know if anything on the users active directory object (eg group membership) has altered since the last time the app was ran.

I was looking at the whenChanged attribute but that appears only to change if the user changes their password. I just need something i can hold in my config file, and check that value in active directory the next time the app is ran.

Anyone know of anything i can reliably use?

Cheers
Luke

Comment: Roughly how many users are you dealing with? If you only need to run the check when your app starts, it may be best to just compare each value you're concerned about individually.

Comment: Its mainly group membership i want to check, i might just have to create a hash based on all the group names and hold that if there is no concrete method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are primarily concerned with groups, I think you'll have to create a hash - modifying group membership won't affect the user object.

Here's a quick example I've knocked up.

```
public static string HashGroups(string user)
{
    DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = default(DirectoryEntry);
    DirectorySearcher dirSearcher = default(DirectorySearcher);

    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<YOUR_DOMAIN>");
    directoryEntry.RefreshCache();

    // Get search object, specify filter and scope, 
    // perform search. 
    dirSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
    dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
    dirSearcher.Filter = "(&(sAMAccountName=" + user + "))";

    SearchResult sr = dirSearcher.FindOne();

    // Enumerate groups 
    foreach (string group in sr.Properties["memberOf"])
    {
        result.Add(group);
    }

    // OrderBy is important! Otherwise, your hash might fail because 
    // the groups come back in different order.
    MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
    Byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result.OrderBy(s1 => s1).SelectMany(s2 => s2).ToArray());
    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

**PREVIOUS (rubbish) ANSWER**
According to the docs, the [Modify-Time-Stamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677125%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) attribute is "A computed attribute representing the date when this object was last changed." which sounds like what you want. It's available in all versions back to 2000.

**EDIT** It looks like this is computed from `whenChanged`, so if that is not working for you then this may not.

Comment: I checked that one before, its just an alias back to whenChanged

Answer (score 1):

You could always check the Directory's properties for last write or modification time and maybe keep some XML or some data that keeps track of last write times of files.